# Incorrect function output when passing NA as arguments in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, na

I am trying to set a range based on numerical arguments,
The function is working fine for every case except when
the two arguments are `NA`;

I would like the function to return NA when `x` and `y` are NA's,
however it keeps me returning a different output..

Here's my code:

```
set_range_function <- function(x, y){
   if(x == 0 && y %in% c(0,1,2)){
                                  return("Menos de 3 meses")
   } else if(x == 0 && y %in% c(3,4,5)){
                                  return("Entre 3 e 6 meses")
   } else if(x == 0 && y %in% c(6,7,8,9,10,11)){
                                  return("Entre 6 e 12 meses")
   } else if(x == 1 && !is.null(y)){
                                  return("Entre 1 a 2 anos") 
   } else if(x == 2 && !is.null(y)){
                                  return("Entre 2 a 3 anos")
   } else if(x %in% c(3,4) && !is.null(y)){
                                  return("Entre 3 e 5 anos")
   } else if(x %in% c(5,6,7,8,9) && !is.null(y)){
                                  return("Entre 5 e 10 anos")
   } else if(x >= 10 && !is.null(y)){
                                  return("Mais de 10 anos")
   } else if(is.na(x) && is.na(y)){
                                  return(NA)
   }  else {
              return(NA)
   }
}


set_range_function(NA, NA)
```

Console output:

```
Error in if (x == 1 && !is.null(y)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE is required
```

Expected output:

```
set_range_function(NA, NA)

[1] NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `NA` values first. Some logical operations on `NA` produce `NA` as a result, and your if statements can get weird. Specifically, checking if `NA` is equal to a non-NA value returns `NA`. Then, `NA & TRUE` evaluates to `NA`.

```
NA == 1
[1] NA
!is.null(NA)
[1] TRUE
NA & TRUE
[1] NA
```

Try moving your last if statement to the top:

```
set_range_function <- function(x, y){
  if(is.na(x) && is.na(y)) {
    return(NA) 
  } else if(x == 0 && y %in% c(0,1,2)){
    return("Menos de 3 meses")
  } else if(x == 0 && y %in% c(3,4,5)){
    return("Entre 3 e 6 meses")
  } else if(x == 0 && y %in% c(6,7,8,9,10,11)){
    return("Entre 6 e 12 meses")
  } else if(x == 1 && !is.null(y)){
    return("Entre 1 a 2 anos") 
  } else if(x == 2 && !is.null(y)){
    return("Entre 2 a 3 anos")
  } else if(x %in% c(3,4) && !is.null(y)){
    return("Entre 3 e 5 anos")
  } else if(x %in% c(5,6,7,8,9) && !is.null(y)){
    return("Entre 5 e 10 anos")
  } else if(x >= 10 && !is.null(y)){
    return("Mais de 10 anos")
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}
set_range_function(NA, NA)
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because `if` needs to have either a `TRUE` or `FALSE` result.

```
if(NA){
    print(1)
}

Error in if (NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```